# How to use the Streaming Monitor app?

Tags: lightning-apps, appexchange, streaming-api, platform-event

I have downloaded the app, installed it, added myself to its permission set. Still, I cannot do anything in the tab. See the screenshot. The AppExchange page does not give any instructions, the Github page ([Github](https://github.com/pozil/streaming-monitor)) does not help. Who can help me out?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You should see something like this:
[image]

Have you tried to check your console log to see if there is any error? What do you see in the app page? Do you see the components there? There should be something wrong on permission level.
Do you have permission for the apex class called StreamingMonitorController?
I've successfully installed many times when I installed it for Admins only.

Comment: I use Chrome. Can't see anything wrong in the Console log. The app page: you mean the packet details? I cannot see or change permission for individual classes, because they belong to a managed package. From the presence of a permission set I concluded that I had to add myself to that, but I haven't found any documentation on how to use/set up the app.

Comment: Additionally: I am admin, I installed the app as being usable by all user. Also, I enabled Change Data Capture for a custom object. No change.